# pip install yahoo-finance with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to install yahoo finance in terminal with **pip install yahoo-finance** so I can run yahoo finance in jupyter notebook. While there's nothing happened after I typed in my terminal, so there's an error said ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yahoo_finance' in jupyter noterbook.

Could someone give me any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output of your run of `pip install yahoo-finance`?

Comment: pip install yahoo-finance
[I 17:40:15.481 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Stock Analysis.ipynb
pip install fix_yahoo_finance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
[I 17:40:53.801 NotebookApp] Kernel restarted: b5d3819d-bdd3-45ef-a70c-a2f4dbf9aae8
[I 17:40:55.449 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel b5d3819d-bdd3-45ef-a70c-a2f4dbf9aae8
[I 17:42:16.557 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Stock Analysis.ipynb
pip show yahoo-finance
pip install yahoo-finance
[I 17:56:16.231 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in

Comment: @ChristianWill There's no output  and this is where it confused me

Comment: If you run it inside of an notebook try `!pip install yahoo-finance` and make sure your cell is marked as `code` and not `markdown` or anything else.
From the terminal you should see something like: `Requirement already satisfied: yahoo-finance in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from yahoo-finance)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from yahoo-finance)
jovyan@jupyter-5546c66f8b-g4t7x:/$`

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late to answer this but I ran this in my Jupyter notebook for Python:

```
!pip install yfinance
```

and it worked correctly. (It also works in Google Colab.) Hope this helped!

Comment: These days for Jupyter that isn't Google Colab, it is best as `%pip install <package_name>`. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for why the exclamation point can cause issues and so why the magic version was added. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands that should be what are recommended in Jupyter for a better experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
conda install -c conda-forge yfinance
```

Comment: And the variation is `%conda install -c conda-forge yfinance` inside a Jupyter notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands for running inside a notebook to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that is underlying the active notebook. Because of automagics generally being the default these days, the magic version should run wihtout any symbol inside a notebook but being explicit is always best.